# How to fix IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to connect my oracle cloud database using sqldeveloper with connection type basic but it fails connection with error:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.
```

Anyone can help how can i connect my oracle db system using sqldevloper with connection type either basic or TNS ??

[image: Input_data]

Comment: That IP address isn't reachable or the port is blocked or firewall or network access list is blocking your IP

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to telnet the server on port 1521?
It sounds likely that the dbsystem is not connected to the internet.

Please check if the dbsystem subnet has:

- Security List with a rule to allow port 1521 on your ip address
- Routing Table that allows internet access via internet gateway